# Another Fabric.js object being added to the canvas on calling canvas.getObjects()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

This is a weird bug I've been getting in my React.js project in which I am using Fabric.js.

Whenever I call the canvas.getObjects() function to get an array of objects on the canvas, the object just duplicates and another one is added.

Example -

```
const exampleFunction = () => {
  console.log(canvas.getObjects());
}
```

The length of the objects array was 1 before this function was executed but afterwards it became 2. This seems peculiar since I never imagined that a console.log would in any way affect this.

I also verified this with other statements such as `var myVar = canvas.getObjects()` and `canvas.remove(canvas.getObjects()[0]` and in each case, another object was added to the canvas.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you encountering this problem after deleting the object?

Comment: @Gucal nope, it's coming up every time I call it. Even when I am deleting and even when I am not. It comes up any time I call the canvas.getObjects() function for any reason.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this bug?

Comment: @Ben I do, but I am using it in junction with another library (React.js), if that helps I will post the example of the bug as soon as I can.

Comment: Run it after adding or deleting it -> `canvas.renderAll();`